# NSURLRequest and target-action

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, target-action

As a novice iOS developer, I am trying to understand some concepts related to the callback mechanisms in iOS.

My model makes HTTP requests through NSURLRequest to a backend rest service. The model has several methods which corresponds to the methods in the service. NSURLRequest is based on the delegate pattern, which means that I receive a common callback for all of the service calls. Then, my model has to find out which service call the callback is related to, so that I can send an appropriate update event to the controller. This is awkward since I have to maintain som state in the model to remember which call I made the last time (which is very impractical in the case of concurrency), or interpret the payload in the HTTP response.

I would wish that NSURLRequest would support the target-action pattern, so that each of the requests could decide which callback method to use. Is that possible? Am I missing something here?

If target-action is not available in the framework, what are the best practices to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to use NSURLRequest with NSURLConnection. If you check out the [docs for NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), they will tell you that you need to implement the callback methods in the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol, and will give you details.

That page also points to several examples, with sample code.

You can also check out the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) at developer.apple.com, which will give you additional information on how these classes are intended to be used.